# ArcGIS Runtime (WPF): Does Layer has FeatureTable property?

Tags: arcgis-runtime, wpf

According to the API reference, there is a [ArcGISSceneLayer#FeatureTable property](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/P_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Mapping_ArcGISSceneLayer_FeatureTable.htm) inherited from `Layer`. However, I can't find this property in my Visual Studios. Is the API reference wrong?

Comment: It may be unexposed (hidden), it wouldn't be the first documented interface that hasn't been fully exposed. What happens if you try to use the property (be sure to get your case correct)?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Visual Studios give me this: `'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.ArcGISSceneLayer' does not contain a definition for 'FeatureTable' and no extension method 'FeatureTable' accepting a first argument of type 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.ArcGISSceneLayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. According to API, it's supposed to be `public`.

Comment: That is indeed a problem. This sounds like a genuine bug that is worth reporting to Esri support. I take it that the layers' feature source has a table to retrieve, it should even if it only contains OID and Shape.

Comment: @MichaelStimson It looks like this was added in ArcGIS Runtime 100.3.0. I was using ArcGIS Runtime 100.2.1.